# laravel installation mcrypt unable to initialize module

Tags: php, laravel, osx-mavericks, mcrypt

im trying to install laravel 4 on my mac mavericks os with xampp server.
I solved several problems but a cant With This:

Warning: PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

i understund the problem , but i dont know how to fix it.
thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)? If so, you need to `brew tap homebrew/php` and then `brew install php55-mcrypt`.

If you're not using Homebrew, then you really should be. (Xampp probably isn't the way to locally develop Laravel either...) Check out Jeffrey Way's http://laracasts.com. There are a couple of free videos in the series Laravel From Scratch that should answer some installation questions.

Comment: yes im using homebrew ! so i should write brew install php55-mcrypt on terminal ? sorry about my english (its my first time using a mac os and a terminal.. )

Comment: which server should I use?

Answer (score 5):

`brew reinstall mcrypt --build-from-source php56-mcrypt --build-from-source`

You may only need the `php56-mcrypt` module.